# Items in a Linked Model Checkbox List dissapear when unchecked

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to filter product results based on Categories and Tags.

A product can have many categories and a category can have many products so it is a many-to-many relationship.

The same goes with Tags.

I would like the filter options to be checked by default (eventually when you select a menu item for example Cat 1, other categories will be unselected in the filter side menu).

The problem I am having now is that when I uncheck a input it disappears from the list. I using a directive to link a list to a group of checkboxes. The list for the menu is different then the model for the group of checkboxes.

I got the directive from here https://github.com/vitalets/checklist-model

Here is demo http://plnkr.co/edit/NjAH4HrTX3qHWw4WmCvb?p=preview

#### Edit:

Your answer works, but I can't have the checkboxes initially checked. In my real code I am getting the list of categories from the server. I think the newly added angular.copy is copying empty list version.

```
$scope.categories = [];
  $scope.currentCategory = {};
  $http.get('/api/v1.0/categories/all').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      angular.copy(orderCategoriesForUser(data.categories), $scope.categories);
      if($scope.categories){
        $scope.currentProduct = $scope.categories[0];
      }
    }
  );
```

#### Edit 2:

I had to set a promise to each $http call and then do

```
categoryPromise = $http.get('/api/v1.0/categories/all').

$q.all([categoryPromise, tagsPromise])
    .then(function(results){
      $scope.sideFilter = {
          'categories': angular.copy($scope.categories),
          'tags': angular.copy($scope.tags),
      };
    });
```

Comment: So, following `Edit 2`, is this all working for you now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your offending line is:

```
$scope.sideFilter = {categories: $scope.categories, 'tags': $scope.tags}
```

The problem is that you're setting the `categories` and `tags` properties to a reference type (object), so changes to those properties will directly change the objects they reference.

A quick fix is to use [`angular.copy`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.copy) in order to set the property to a deep copy of the object:

```
$scope.sideFilter = {categories: angular.copy($scope.categories), 'tags': angular.copy($scope.tags)};
```

[Fork of your Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1r1k7eyROYniq5Xb1hgD?p=preview)

Comment: You're right. Except now I can't seem to have the checkboxes initially checked. I've added more context to my question.